# VSCode Docker Compose Up command customization with docker-compose.yaml in different folders

Tags: docker, docker-compose, visual-studio-code

I have a project composed of many microservices developed in Java intended to be run in Docker containers. These microservices work without any errors and the containers communicate well between them using Docker CLI, but I'm having trouble configuring VSCode Docker Extension settings to be able to do some [Command Customization](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/reference#_command-customization).

I have all the folders of every microservice I'm working on in the same Workspace and also a folder with my configurations for Docker similar to this:

```
├── first-service
├── second-service    
├── third-service
├── fouth-service
├── fifth-service
├── (...)
├── containerfiles
│   ├── my_config_1
│   │   ├── docker-compose.yaml
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── my_config_2
│   │   ├── artifact
│   │   │   └── first-service.jar
│   │   ├── config-files
│   │   ├── docker-compose.yaml
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── my_config_3
│       ├── artifact
│       │   └── second-service.jar
│       ├── docker-compose.yaml
│       └── Dockerfile
```

I had trouble understanding what files and how to change them (I've read the documentation but it's not as clear as I think it should...) and I finally get the following to work.

In `my_workspace.code-workspace` file under `settings` module I have:

```
"settings": {
    "docker.commands.composeUp": [
        {
            "label": "first-service",
            "template": "docker-compose ${configurationFile} up ${detached} ${build}",
            "match": "first-service"
        },
        {
            "label": "second-service",
            "template": "docker-compose ${configurationFile} up ${detached} ${build}",
            "match": "second-service"
        }
    ],

(...)
}
```

For this to work, I need to right-click the *docker-compose.yaml* file and select Compose Up for these custom commands to work just for two I've done tests.

### Summary

The question is: Is there a way to be able to use this folder
structure and my different Docker files in different folders than the
microservices with the command: <kbd>F1</kbd> > **Docker: Compose Up** > *Select workspace folder* in some way to avoid having to right-click the docker-compose files? (As these are shared with many microservices depending on which one is it)

At present if I use this option I got the following:

Couldn't find any docker-compose files in your workspace.
Would you like to add Docker files to the workspace?

Answering YES forces me to create new Docker files in every microservice folder and I don't want this.

Comment: That seems like a crazy setup. You would expect multiple dockerfiles, one for each service (located with the service, and then ONE docker compose file to run them and configure networking, ports, runtime variables etc. Are you sure you have docker-compose files everywhere ?

Comment: @Chai Well in fact those `containerfiles/my_config_X` folders are categories of microservices, let's say. my_config_1 applies to some microservices, my_config_2 applies to several others only and so. So I have 3 pairs of `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose` files for about 36 microservices.